# Implementation of a FIFO with a ByteArray with reading from fifo while FIFO is still being written to

Tags: actionscript-3

I am sure I am missing something fundamental related to actionscript 3, but I have not had much experience using it

The background of my question:

sound recorded form a microphone needs to be sent via a prop http based protocol (using Secure Socket) to the backend. for that to happen, the voice bytes are "framed" (i.e. some framing bytes are injected *before* the recorded bytes) every 20ms (or 80 bytes with the codec in use) and pushed out via the open socket connection.

So I thought the best approach to get that going is to store the recorded datasamples into a bytearray B that is still being written to when every 80 bytes I would

- read the last recorded 80 bytes from B
- prepend the framing bytes
- push the resulting bytearray out the socket

Now if I read from the bytearray B the operation resets the pointer of the bytearrya and when a new voicebyte comes in that will surely overwrite the bytes after the pointer?

How can I avoid that to happen?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Note the docs state you can reset the pointer ([position](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#position)) of the `ByteArray`:

> Moves, or returns the current position, in bytes, of the file pointer into the ByteArray object. This is the point at which the next call to a read method starts reading or a write method starts writing.

So you could reset the `position` before doing your read operations and manage the FIFO that way.

But I think using a byte array as the FIFO may be problematic:

- You would want to remove the bytes you just read from the FIFO, I don't see any API to do that, other than `clear()` which clears the whole array.
- It's possible the `SampleDataEvents` from the mic will come in so frequently that this becomes less efficient or problematic

It might be easier to just keep make a FIFO (with an Array) of the individual ByteArray's you get from each SampleDataEvent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Nice ide to pack samples into arrays. I'll look into if I can use this approach.